# Displaying checkbox selected rows with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm starting out with vuejs and a vue grid  at https://jsfiddle.net/kc11/7fqgavvq/2/.

I want to  display the checked row objects in the:

```
    <pre> {{ selected| json}} </pre>
```

at the bottom of the table. I've come across [Check all checkboxes vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571382/check-all-checkboxes-vuejs) with an associated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/okv0rgrk/206/ that shows what I mean if you look at the outputted Selected Ids.

To get this working I'll need to add a method to the table component similar to

```
methods: {
    selectAll: function() {
        this.selected = [];
        for (user in this.users) {
            this.selected.push(this.users[user].id);
        }
    }
```

in https://jsfiddle.net/okv0rgrk/206/

Can someone explain this function as I am having trouble in particular with what 'this' means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to your component.  So anything inside of your component can be called using `this`.  You can access data with `this.users` or `this.selected`, run methods with `this.selectAll()` or access anything else in your component.

In that fiddle, there is a `users` attribute on the data, so `this.users` refers to that array.  The function `selectAll()` empties the `this.selected` array, then goes through and re-adds every user to the array, `this.selected`.

Edit -- computed properties

Add this to your component:

```
computed:{
    userCount: function(){
        return this.users.length;
    }
}
```

then, anywhere in this component, `this.userCount` will return the number of users.  This variable will update anytime the number of users changes.  That is why its a "computed" property - you don't have to update, it just automatically recalculates when it needs to.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that helps a lot. As quick follow up if I may: In https://jsfiddle.net/kc11/7fqgavvq/2/ I'm using a vue component which has its own methods. To write a method that counts the checkboxes should I write the method in the vue instance methods or in the component methods?

Comment: Within the component, `this` refers to the component, and that sort of thing belongs to the component.  You can use a computed property for this, so after your `methods:{}` you could include an object called `computed:{}`.  The methods within computed can be accessed like normal variables.  See my edit for how this would work

Comment: To clarify my earlier answer, `this` always refers to the current component you are in, not the original vue instance.  I'll edit to clarify that.