# Select all checkbox with Vue.js (issues with for looping inside a .vue file)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js

I am looking for how to do a "Select All" checkbox with Vue.js and actually a I kind of found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571382/check-all-checkboxes-vuejs).

The problem is I am using Vueify and doing everything on my .vue file so some syntax is different then on the example and I can't fix it!

My problem is on this part of the [FiddleJS](https://jsfiddle.net/okv0rgrk/466/)

```
for (user in this.users) {
    this.userIds.push(this.users[user].id);
}
```

This for is not recognized on my code I don't know why! If I insert a console.log(user) inside the for it returns:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined

Somebody knows what is happening?

Comment: Is the Reference Error from the browser or from Vue? It is impossible to get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined` in JS as `console.log(myUndefinedVariable)` is valid. Check what the real generated JS is. I'd also add a `for(var user in this.users)`.

Comment: Good question RainingChain! I don't know how to distingue it! The error is showing on the browser console so I guess it's from the browser right? Btw adding var solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys it is simpler them I thought! As @RainingChain helped me on the comment above I jus need to add var to the for loop.

**How I was doing**

```
for (user in this.users) {
    this.userIds.push(this.users[user].id);
}
```

**The right way to do**

```
for (var user in this.users) {
    this.userIds.push(this.users[user].id);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely. Your fix in your fiddle does not work for me. But works my fix in your html:

**Your code:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" v-model="userIds" value="{{ user.id }}"></td>
```

**My code:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" v-model="userIds" :value="user.id"></td>
```

Even without var in loop.